# Are the new data-* HTML5/Javascript values accessible in PHP when submited in forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Ok so I've got this ongoing project. That I'm working. Which amounts to a web app. I discovered that data-* values can be used to add Javascript accessible data to page.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp for more details.

My question is will this data be exposed in forms submitted to PHP or will I need to compact the data into element ID's as CSV type values seperated with say a tilda `~`

A related concern is whether it's possible to loop through all object's of either a specified ID, class, or element type (in JS and/or PHP) and retrieve data from each element's data-* attribute's in turn. The purpose being to run logic operations and also (on the PHP side) submitting data to a database.

The following is my 'app' as it stands currently. Using the add row button will reveal why I need access to data-* attributes. At this stage I'm thinking two would be enough. data-scene and data-row and writing those values in PHP as they're leaving the database is of no concern but getting them back is apparently not documented currently. :/ I certainly can't find anything.
http://azarel-howard.me/stage-management/script-writer/

Comment: No, that `data-` attributes reside in the DOM nodes only. A `<form>` submit won't pick them up without the approach you already mentioned.

Comment: i believe they aren't

Comment: The dataset properties are only accessible to Javascript. They won't be written back to the server. However, there's nothing to stop you using Javascript to copy the values into hidden `<input>` fields in the `submit()` event handler.

Comment: http://w3fools.com - [The Mozilla Developer Network describes much better what data-attributes are.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: can send any data structure you want to server using ajax also. So withn a form submittal could loop over any number of elements and compile objects or arrays to send

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. And yes @charlietfl I was beginning to think that I was going to end up using AJAX this is designed to be a dynamic site after all. Ok sweet I'm accepting user2864740 answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formalized addition of the `data-*` attributes does *not* affect how HTML forms work. They act *no differently* than any other attribute with respect to forms.

*Only* values of named `input` child controls (that are not disabled) will be posted with a standard HTML form submission.

How such input elements are created is left open: e.g. they can be added dynamically on the client with JavaScript or the server can add additional hidden fields when generating the HTML.